# Wordpress custom user table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have defined a custom user table in my wp-config.

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
```

But, when i try to print out the logged in user info, user_level seems to be missing and the roles is empty. Any idea?

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using only a single users table for multiple WordPress installations, WordPress will only generate the user role for the WordPress installation that you create the user on.

So, if you create `john_doe` on `site1`, `john_doe` will be assigned a user role on `site1` *(be it administrator, editor, author, etc)*, but `site2` will not assign `john_doe` a user role.  This is known as an "orphaned role."  When `john_doe` logs into `site2`, he will receive a `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page` error message.

So, you can either manually add the role into the usermeta database, or have an admin update the user's role for that installation, or finally you can use a plugin. I found a plugin that makes managing orphaned user roles much easier.  It is called **WP-Orphanage Extended**.

I also created a video screencast explaining the whole issue, and showing how to use a single users table for multiple WordPress sites.  You can find it here: http://mikemclin.net/single-users-table-multiple-wordpress-sites/

Answer (score 0):

user roles are stored in `wp_options` with option_name: `wp_user_roles`
Does that exist, or is it empty?
Are all your tables prefixed with '`wp_`'?

if so.
In `wp_usermeta` you have to set meta_key: `wp_user_level`
Also check meta_key `wp_capabilities`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently and have a solution that works. We had a multisite but moved to sprat installs using subfolders for caching reasons (W3 Total Cache broke our multisite).

So we defined the user tables in `wpconfig` and we user `wp_` for our main and `wp_2_` for the second and this function in the theme function file worked:

```
add_action('set_current_user', '_super_set_current_user', 10);
    function _super_set_current_user()
    {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if($user_id==0){ return;}
        
        $metadats = array('wp_capabilities' => 'wp_2_capabilities','wp_user_level' => 'wp_2_user_level');
        
        $x = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_2_capabilities', true );
        // Update user meta
        if ( !is_array( $x ) )
        {
            foreach($metadats as $s1 => $s2)
            {
                $v = get_user_meta( $user_id, $s1, true );
                update_user_meta($user_id, $s2, $v);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So this fetches the `wp_` user settings from the old site and then converts them to the new site and just adds the meta data for the user but only if it does not exist.